# JAXBException when running lint test

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, lint

I have an app that pass a lint test on circleCI, but fail on local machine with the following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3090)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3295)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:532)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.ServiceLoaderLite.loadImplementations(ServiceLoaderLite.kt:50)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension$loadProcessors$efficientProcessorLoader$1.doLoadProcessors(Kapt3Extension.kt:83)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorLoader.loadProcessors(ProcessorLoader.kt:45)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorLoader.loadProcessors$default(ProcessorLoader.kt:28)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.loadProcessors(Kapt3Extension.kt:88)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:171)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:106)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:82)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:384)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:70)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:375)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:123)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:131)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:54)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:103)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:442)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1027)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1069)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1026)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:441)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor111.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
        ... 48 more
```

I do not use JAXB and I have no idea where does this come from. More frustrating is I can build my app without any error.

I have tried the solutions in the following links, but none of them works for my case.
https://www.concretepage.com/questions/556

[How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)

Has anyone experienced similar issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit 10/2020:
I ran into this issue again some time ago when CircleCi update their java image from jdk8 to jdk11. I was able to solve this issue by updating the Gradle tool. Looks like in the latest version of Gradle `lint` no longer use JAXB APIs.

Old answer: Today I finally solve this issue. Here is what I did.

1. I attempted to solve this issue by reinstalling Android Studio 3.4. However I couldn't even start up Android Studio and I ran into this

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: 
Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
```

2. Then I looked for answers and came across this page
   [Can't start Android Studio][1]
   [1]: https://superuser.com/questions/1391452/cant-start-android-studio
3. I reverted back to use jdk 8.
4. Android Studio 3.4 finally started up, and JAXBException was gone.

Answer (score 0):

The JAXB APIs are considered to be J2EE APIs, therefore not present default class path in Java SE 9. In JDK 11 they are completely removed. But, these Java EE APIs that were provided in JDK 6/7/8 are still in the JDK.

Comment: Yes. But the thing is I am not using any of the JAXB api and this is the first time that I know of this api. So is there any way that I can disable the use of this api?

Comment: JAX-RS implementations automatically support marshalling/unmarshalling of classes. It is used by Spring to convert object coming from API to JAVA object and vice-versa.

Comment: So whats the solution in case of android

Comment: you can add them in the classpath